# Is there some trick to programmatically determine whether a given Twitch username is streaming without using their API?

Tags: http, web, curl, browser, twitch

*Prolog: Twitch has locked me out from their site due to extreme incompetence. I'm not banned, but might as well be in practice. As a result, I no longer have access to their API either. When creating a new account, it was revealed that they demand "2FA" to access their API now, meaning having to enter a surveillance unit number, meaning I can't ever access it again.*

With that out of the way, is there some way to programmatically determine whether a given Twitch user is live or not?

Of course, I have loaded a test stream webpage such as `https://www.twitch.tv/Czech_Meowt` and scanned the HTML for any "checkable" strings such as "isLive", but the only instances are just JS variable names, and everything seems to be built with JavaScript in an extremely convoluted manner, seemingly engineered to make it impossible to extract any useful information from the webpage.

I've also checked all the "JSON blobs" that are loaded in with JS, but they are of no help and I cannot reproduce the loading of those.

In many other cases, I am able to simply fetch the HTML page and check for the existence of a string such as "X is streaming", but on Twitch, it just seems impossible.

Is there some secret trick to determine this?

Comment: hi, perhaps use headless chrome to instrument the web page including javascript

Comment: @jspcal Yeah, but that's easier said than done. I've actually looked for many years for a usable project which does "headless Chrome", but never found one. They are all abandoned/unsupported/broken, sadly.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to fetch the stream preview from the link

`https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_NICKNAME-440x248.jpg`

If the streamer `NICKNAME` is online, it will get the image, otherwise it will redirect to

`https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-static/404_preview-440x248.jpg`

In next example I reduce the requested image resolution to 1x1 and use a HEAD request method with disabled redirections to increase a throughput.

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.status'),
      button = document.querySelector('.reload-btn')

button.onclick = reloadStatuses

function reloadStatuses() {
  for (const status of elements) {
    delete status.dataset.online
    const nick = status.dataset.nick
    const url = `https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_${nick}-1x1.jpg`

    fetch(url, {
      method: 'HEAD',
      redirect: 'manual'
    }).then(res => status.dataset.online = res.ok)
  }
}

reloadStatuses()
```

```css
.status::before {
  content: "LOADING";
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font: 1em Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  
  color: #544d00;
  background: #fff476;
}

.status[data-online="true"]::before {
  content: "ONLINE";
  color: #376136;
  background: #87ff85;
}

.status[data-online="false"]::before {
  content: "OFFLINE";
  color: #4c1511;
  background: #ff746a;
}
```

```html
<button class="reload-btn">Reload</button>
<p>Soundtrack: <span class="status" data-nick="Soundtrack"></span></p>
<p>Myth: <span class="status" data-nick="Myth"></span></p>
<p>TheGrefg: <span class="status" data-nick="TheGrefg"></span></p>
<p>Pokimane: <span class="status" data-nick="Pokimane"></span></p>
<p>Auronplay: <span class="status" data-nick="Auronplay"></span></p>
<p>shroud: <span class="status" data-nick="shroud"></span></p>
<p>Rubius: <span class="status" data-nick="Rubius"></span></p>
<p>Tfue: <span class="status" data-nick="Tfue"></span></p>
<p>Ninja: <span class="status" data-nick="Ninja"></span></p>
```